# Const value is not updating

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script to update a progress bar and after my function runs the first time, the value for the const I declared to read the style does not change.

```js
var progNumVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('#formProgNumVal').style.width, 10);

console.log(progNumVal); // 70 as expected

function handleFormProgBar() {
  console.log("starting")
  document.getElementById("formProgNumVal").style.width = `${progNumVal + 10}%`;
  document.getElementById("formProgTextVal").innerHTML = `${progNumVal + 10}% complete`;
  console.log("stopped")
};

handleFormProgBar();

console.log(progNumVal); // 70 instead of 80
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="form-progress">
        <span><div class="progress">
            <div id="formProgNumVal"class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="formProgTextVal" class="primary-text">70% complete</p></span>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm really new to coding, so I'm not sure what questions to ask in order to find out why this is the case. Does anyone have an explanation or any direction on how to research this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never update the value though. You say `progNumVal =` only at the beginning, if you want it to change you have to do it again with a new value.

Comment: Where are you actually updating progNumVal ? JavaScript values are not "reactive", if you need a calculation to repeat you put it in a function and call it :]

Comment: Numbers are immutable in Javascript. To change a number, you need to reassign a different value to it.

Comment: By the way, you have defined a `var`, not a `const`. The difference is very relevant here, because the whole point of `const` declared variables is to prevent re-assigning a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable name will (almost) never suddenly change to a different value unless you explicitly tell the interpreter to reassign it with the `=` assignment operator. You need a *function* that returns the current value instead:

```js
var getNum = () => parseInt(document.querySelector('#formProgNumVal').style.width, 10);

console.log(getNum());

function handleFormProgBar() {
  console.log("starting")
  const progNumVal = getNum();
  document.getElementById("formProgNumVal").style.width = `${progNumVal + 10}%`;
  document.getElementById("formProgTextVal").innerHTML = `${progNumVal + 10}% complete`;
  console.log("stopped")
};

handleFormProgBar();

console.log(getNum());
```

```html
<div id="form-progress">
  <span><div class="progress">
            <div id="formProgNumVal"class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="formProgTextVal" class="primary-text">70% complete</p></span>
</div>
```

If you don't like concise arrow functions, you can use a `function` instead:

```js
var getNum = function() {
  return parseInt(document.querySelector('#formProgNumVal').style.width, 10);
};

console.log(getNum());

function handleFormProgBar() {
  console.log("starting")
  const progNumVal = getNum();
  document.getElementById("formProgNumVal").style.width = `${progNumVal + 10}%`;
  document.getElementById("formProgTextVal").innerHTML = `${progNumVal + 10}% complete`;
  console.log("stopped")
};

handleFormProgBar();

console.log(getNum());
```

```html
<div id="form-progress">
  <span><div class="progress">
            <div id="formProgNumVal"class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="formProgTextVal" class="primary-text">70% complete</p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think introducing lambdas at this stage of learning is overkill when they could just update the value in the function

Comment: Good answer, probably a good idea to mention that `.textContent` is preferable to `.innerHTML` for setting an element's content to avoid XSS

Comment: @BrandonDyer I don't like recommending using reassignment when not necessary - it often makes code harder to understand at a glance. A function really is the most appropriate method to use here.

Comment: @BrandonDyer I disagree, I think a function here is the simple and appropriate solution for a "value that can update and needs re-calculation" compared to other approaches (like updating it from every call site) - though I might suggest a regular (non-arrow) function since OP is already familiar with those.

Comment: Yes, of course it's a good solution, and one I would probably use, but OP is obviously very new to programming.

Comment: Thank you, that does make perfect sense. The arrow function worked great. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expression `${progNumVal + 10}%`, it takes the value of `progNumVal` and adds 10 to it and evaluates the result.

The original variable `progNumVal` remains unchanged. You never assign to the variable the new value of the expression.

```js
var progNumVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('#formProgNumVal').style.width, 10);

console.log(progNumVal); // 70 as expected

function handleFormProgBar() {
  console.log("starting")
  //Assign the new value here
  progNumVal = progNumVal + 10
  document.getElementById("formProgNumVal").style.width = `${progNumVal}%`;
  document.getElementById("formProgTextVal").innerHTML = `${progNumVal}% complete`;
  console.log("stopped")
};

handleFormProgBar();

console.log(progNumVal); // 70 instead of 80
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="form-progress">
        <span><div class="progress">
            <div id="formProgNumVal"class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="formProgTextVal" class="primary-text">70% complete</p></span>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are not updating progNumVal in handleFormProgBar function. Also you may pass the amount of progress to add as a parameter, that may be helpful

```js
var progNumVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('#formProgNumVal').style.width, 10);


function handleFormProgBar(progress) {
  console.log("starting")
  progNumVal = progNumVal + progress;
  document.getElementById("formProgNumVal").style.width = `${progNumVal}%`;
  document.getElementById("formProgTextVal").innerHTML = `${progNumVal }% complete`;
  console.log("stopped")
};

handleFormProgBar(10);

console.log(progNumVal); // 70 instead of 80
```

```css
.progress
{
width:100;
background-color:black;
height:50px;
}

.determinate
{
background-color:green;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="form-progress">
        <span><div class="progress">
            <div id="formProgNumVal"class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="formProgTextVal" class="primary-text">70% complete</p></span>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As others mentioned, to get a different value, you need to **assign** a different value first. The concept behind that is called *immutability*.

Also, I removed unnecessary parts of the HTML and jQuery (which your code isn't using anyway).

The point of my answer is to show you **how to both increase and reassign in one step** using the `+=` operator:

```js
var progNumVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('#formProgNumVal').style.width, 10);

console.log(progNumVal); // 70 as expected

function handleFormProgBar() {
  console.log("starting")
  document.getElementById("formProgNumVal").style.width = `${progNumVal += 10}%`;
  /*                                                                    ^^   */
  document.getElementById("formProgTextVal").innerHTML = `${progNumVal}% complete`;
  console.log("stopped")
};

handleFormProgBar();

console.log(progNumVal); // 80 as expected
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div id="formProgNumVal"class="determinate" style="width: 70%"></div>
</div>
<p id="formProgTextVal" class="primary-text">70% complete</p>
```